# Best Strategy for Sending Email from a .Net Application

Tags: .net, email

I'm rethinking the way my .net application handles the sending of email and wanted to get the thoughts of the development community.

Basically, the application lives as an Azure App and uses the Azure SQL database as the backend storage.

Right now, any time I need to send an email (like a 2FA code), I write it to a table name "tblMailLog" in the SQL database.  Then I have a small app running as a WebJob that reads the table every 5 seconds. If it finds an unsent message, it send it and then flags the message as sent. If the WebJob app is unable to send the message, it flags it as failed and stores the mail server's error message back in the table. This works well as it lets me read the table as an activity log and change the message status flag, resubmitting the message back to the WebJob app if needed.  One exception to this flow is if  the website/app runs into a runtime error.  If that happens, I bypass the "tblMailLog" table and I send the message directly to the mail server.

Now perhaps I'm over thinking this... This strategy and process does not appear to use a great deal of resources, but a quick 5 sec hit on the SQL DB does use resources. So I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better approach.